# React undefined item after redux delete

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

```
import {deleteTodo} from "../actions/todos";

@connect(store => {
    return {
        todos: store.todos.todos,
    }
})
class ViewTodo extends React.Component{
    handleDelete(id){
        this.props.history.goBack();
        //even if the deleteTodo() method is after the goBack(), it still throws error
        this.props.dispatch(deleteTodo(id));
    }
    render(){
        const todo = this.props.todos.filter(e => parseInt(this.props.match.params.id) === e.id)[0];
        return (
            <div>
                <TodoDeleteButton
                    onDelete={() => this.handleDelete(todo.id)}
                />

                <h2>{todo.title}</h2>
```

When the current todo element is deleted, react is trying to render the new `{todo.title}` but the todo element is missing and it throws an  error. Is there any way to avoid this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
todo.title ? todo.title : ''
```

This way if there is a title it will try and load it, otherwise it will just load an empty h2 element.